# How to empty specific char array positions

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have a 200-elements-long char array, I load the vector with new characters in a loop, and
at each cycle the element number can be different from the previous one, so how can I empty the unwanted position of the array?
Note: the element size have to be of 200 and I can't resolve the problem creating a new instance of the object with new.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
Arrays.fill(array, index, array.length, '\0');
```

? Of course, that will just overwrite the rest of the array with U+0000 values... there's no such thing as a `char[]` element being "empty". There will *always* be a `char` at every element in the array; U+0000 is *one* way of indicating "don't treat this as real data".

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to delete characters, I would use a StringBuilder. This is more efficient than using a Vector.

```
char[] chars = new char[50];
Arrays.fill(chars, '-');

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(chars);
// remove characters 10 to 15.
sb.delete(10, 15);
// remove a character
sb.deleteCharAt(24);
// replace some characters
sb.replace(30, 40, "Hello World");

System.out.println(sb);
```

prints

```
------------------------------Hello World----
```